# Convert a youtube video into mp3 file?

Tags: python

Does Any one know how to convert a Youtube video into an mp3 file. The solution needs to be in python.
let me give more details is there a module or way to extract the embedded video that is in the youtube webpage?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can't expect someone to just write a program for you

Comment: whoa that was alot of downvotes...let me give more details is there a module or way to extract the embedded video that is in the youtube webpage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this script will do it: http://code.google.com/p/pymp/

Edit: Probably not what you're looking for, assuming you wanted a non-graphical script that ran in the background of one of your programs.

Comment: No this will work thank you ill just edit the code a little

Comment: Another script, no GUI
https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl